# Info-path view item issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-rules

I am using info-path set up rule to display fields as per the rule.
The rule is working fine in edit and new item, but if you go to view item, that is behaving strange. the rule is not applying in view item form.

Please do help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following points for your issue:

- What's the rules you set in the InfoPath form?
- Check if that value that you use the rule is blank or overwritten in 
  display form.
- Recreate the InfoPath form or create in another list, check if the issue still exits.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the rule I set for edit and new form and display form are completely different. So I changed the rule as same as edit form rule in display form rule.

Everything worked like champ...